# tracking mouse position on Java WorldWind

Tags: worldwind

I am trying to add a mouse listener to my globe using `addMouseListener`. It does not show any error, I am even able to add a `mouseClicked(MouseEvent e)`, and still no errors. But finally when I am trying to get the current position using `worldWindowGLCanvas1.getCurrentPosition()` it shows NULL, even if I am clicking on the globe or outside... Can someone help me with doing this? Don't worry about extra spaces. I have modified since the website was not accepting my question :)

Comment: Could you add your code to this post? There are still a lot of questions I have. I added an answer that works for me, but I'm not sure what you've already done. Where did you adde a mouseClicked method? See my answer and let me know if that helps.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not sure if this is what you're asking, but this was working for me:

```
final WorldWindowGLCanvas aCanvas = new WorldWindowGLCanvas();
aCanvas.setModel(new BasicModel());
aCanvas.getInputHandler().addMouseListener(new MouseAdapter() {
    @Override
    public void mouseClicked(MouseEvent pE) {

        Position aCurrentPosition = aCanvas.getCurrentPosition();

        //Or whatever work:      
        if(aCurrentPosition != null) {

            System.out.println("Current Pos= " + aCurrentPosition);

        } else {

            System.out.println("Current Pos is null!");

        }
    }
});
```

I added the null check to see if it would ever get null and it did not.  The assumption this code is making is that a mouse click will re-center the globe to that position. Calling the aCanvas.getCurrentPosition() should return the center globe. If the canvas is not rendered or isn't visible, then this method would return null.